# AsyncTask context menu

Tags: android, web-services

My problem is the following, i have this assynctask that gets the id of a product i want to delete. But i cant pass the right id, because i want to use a context menu to select the item i want to eleminate. i alredy got the id that want on my context menu but when i pass it to my asynctask it doesnt recognize what can i do.

I did:

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:


        HashMap <String, String> product = productsList.get(info.position);
        final String name = product.get(TAG_ID);
        // Starting new intent


        new DeleteProduct().execute();

          return true;
```

here i get the id of the item and pass it to the name variable.Then:

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", name));
```

I pass it to the asynctask but it doesnt recognize

Full code:

```
 /*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", name));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}



@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:


        HashMap <String, String> product = productsList.get(info.position);
        final String name = product.get(TAG_ID);
        // Starting new intent


        new DeleteProduct().execute();

          return true;


    case R.id.item2:


        return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can send params to AsyncTask for example

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29), it should be pretty clear.

Change the invocation of the task to:

```
  final String name = product.get(TAG_ID);
        // Starting new intent
        new DeleteProduct().execute( name ); // pass the name here
```

And then read it out in the AsyncTask like so:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = args[0]; // receive the argument here
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", name));
```